# Identify part and how/where to order it from

Tags: pcb, identification, components, surface-mount

I'm trying to fix a board in my overhead fan unit above my oven (there was a power event at the house). I have located the chip that was burned, but couldn't identify the chip.

I was forced to purchase the replacement board and now have a good ID on the part needed.  I would like to try and repair the old one, and if possible swap it back in the unit and sell the now nearly new one.

So could someone please help me identify the chip? I can see ST1S14 but I'm not sure what the 8202 means. I just want to buy the correct part. Here's the pictures of the old and new chips.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that the ST1S14 may not be the only thing "bad" on that board.  There should also be a MOSFET and high-speed rectifier diode(s) nearby.  Either or all of those can also be damaged (shorted), and replacing this one part could just cause it to fail again.

Comment: I too am curious as to what 8202 means. Some sort of factory batch number maybe? How do the answerers below know to disregard it as irrevelant? (To be certain, I would find datasheets from multiple sources, and if they don't indicate that the ST1S14 has multiple variants, maybe it's safe to ignore the 8202?)

Comment: @user234461 It's normal for chips to be labeled with batch codes. The answerers know it's irrelevant because it would be staggeringly weird for the data sheet (from the one source that matters, the manufacturer) to pretend there weren't different variants.

Comment: Normally 8202 as a datecode would mean week 2 of 1982, but that doesn't look right for this part - that package wasn't popular until the late 80s at least.  It is possible that they only use a batch code due to limited space and omit a datecode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the part number it appears to be a [ST1S14](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/st1s14.pdf), switching regulator.

That identifies the part, as for where to buy it, buying recommendations are considered off topic but you should be able to find it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

It's made by ST Microelectronics and is a buck converter type [ST1S14](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/389/st1s14-1849926.pdf): -

[image]

> *I'm not sure what the 8202 means*

It's probably a date or batch code so don't worry about it. [Mouser](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/STMicroelectronics/ST1S14PHR?qs=NQm4g1eHia4Ogn8sLa%252BqDg%3D%3D&gclid=Cj0KCQjw2cWgBhDYARIsALggUhqRX8zXIAEvRgN96u7Uz9UWTNd1EPAgAKhVjKNkiORxY5flMAMzoQwaAnAyEALw_wcB) have over 60,000 in stock.

Comment: Wow, thank you everyone.  I'll get one ordered right away, and I'll report back with the results.

Answer (score 3):

STMicroelectronics is the manufacturer and ST1S14 is a part number in their catalog. This is a switching regulator. Your picture doesn't show enough circuitry around the part, but if there's an inductor, safe bet it's a switching regulator.

You don't say which country you are in, but if you're in the U.S.Digikey and Mouser has thousands of these parts in stock. Simply entering the part number in a Web search brought up this information.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the case for this component, but often if you have a part number, the datasheet will tell you what all the other markings represent. Take this datasheet for example, page 210. https://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet2/4/087t7uwc220l57ih3xi3jps5arky.pdf